# What is the point of using this forum if every question I ask about LWC superbadge is closed before I can get an answer?

Tags: discussion

What is the point of using this forum if every question I ask about LWC superbadge is closed before I can get an answer ?

Comment: Please also reference this [in-progress discussion](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/on-our-new-wave-of-trailhead-questions-2020).

Comment: @DavidReed thanks for providing this link. It's good reading.

Comment: maybe it could be a good idea to refer to the reasons why the question has been closed rather than closing it without any explanations, it is a bit brutal and condescending (in my opinion)

Comment: @EMG Thank you for that feedback. I think that we broadly agree as a community that question closure should provide clear, actionable feedback to the asker. I'm sorry that your experience did not reflect that objective on our part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Our most recent discussion](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/on-our-new-wave-of-trailhead-questions-2020) here on sfse-meta saw wide support by participating community members for disallowing superbadge questions.

The general idea is that superbadges aren't meant as a tool for learning (like the various trailhead modules are), but rather an *exam* that is meant to test your proficiency. If you can't pass it without help, then you shouldn't be awarded the superbadge.

superbadge questions also tend to be formatted like:

- error in title
- code dump
- help plz

which doesn't really demonstrate research effort, or a desire to learn what the issue is *and how to avoid it in the future*.

That, to me, really goes against what I feel is the core of this site. I won't speak for others (even though I suspect many of our active contributors share my sentiment), but the core of this site to me is that we help people get better at using/customizing Salesforce.

Solving someone's problem for them mostly just conceals (temporarily) a lack of experience or ability. Helping people understand their problems, the possible solutions, and *why* the solution works helps build experience and ability.

Answer (score 9):

I don't disagree with Derek, but I want to frame the issue a little bit differently.

We have a longstanding policy on Stack Exchange of not providing answers to or assistance on exams. Exams, of course, are meant to be completed individually as a demonstration of one's own capabilities, but from a different angle, questions about exams do not provide community value to our knowledge base about implementation on the Salesforce platform - our raison d'etre.

I think the area we're negotiating right now is to what extent questions about superbadge challenges fall within that established policy.

My personal opinion is that questions about how to pass Superbadge challenges are clearly exam questions and are therefore off topic. That applies doubly for the LWC Superbadge, which is part of the JavaScript Developer certification. Questions about code for a superbadge that *does not work* on its own merits (not related to the challenge checker) *may* be on topic, but need to be framed very carefully and include minimal code, because the community is being vigilant about the perception of sharing exam material.

Comment: I've answered *one* (and promptly got a downvote for it), but the answer would have been relevant if not framed as a superbadge question. I think you're on the right track. Sharing exam material definitely shouldn't be encouraged, but a question that has to do with a fundamental feature of the language may be.

Comment: Yes asking questions about a super badge requires high proficiency in MVR methodology. Proper isolation is key. Therefore, on any such question it would likely be valid to remove the superbadge tag altogether.